# TinyTeX: Font TS1/ntxtlf/m/n/12=ts1-qtmr at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, installing, installing-fonts, font-metrics

I'm trying to get a minimal LaTeX working inside a Docker container to support some documentation generation. Currently this is what I have going:

```
RUN wget -qO- "https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/raw/master/tools/install-unx.sh" | sh
ENV PATH "$PATH:/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux"
RUN tlmgr install standalone preview ucs was newtx fontaxes xcolor dvisvgm psnfss symbol
```

Whenever I try to compile a document, I get the error message:

```
Font TS1/ntxtlf/m/n/12=ts1-qtmr at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

Here's one example document. This is generated by a tool ([m.css](https://mcss.mosra.cz/plugins/math-and-code/)), which is why it's using way more packages than it needs to. Modifying the docker environment is easy, but modifying the actual document is very difficult.

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
$O(2^{N})$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Note that my end goal here is to get the smallest Docker image that works to compile documents similar to that. Yes, I can `apt-get install texlive-full` and everything will work, but I'd rather figure out the minimal set of fonts and packages needed.

More generally, is there a way to go from that error message to the name of the package I need and/or the fonts that are missing? `TS1/ntxtlf/m/n/12=ts1-qtmr` isn't very googleable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX can not find `ts1-qtmr.tfm`

If you issue the command

```
tlmgr info ts1-qtmr.tfm
```

then amongst other things it reports

```
Packages containing files matching `ts1-qtmr.tfm':
tex-gyre:
        texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/tex-gyre/ts1-qtmr.tfm
```

so

```
  tlmgr install tex-gyre
```

would move things along.

Comment: Thanks! So basically take the last part of the message (`12=ts1-qtmr`), cut off the font size, add `.tfm`, then search that with `tlmgr info`? Is that a good general way to find the fonts?

Comment: @RobertFraser it's a good way to find _anything_ tex related, if you had `\usepackage{wibble}` and tex said it couldn't find `wibble.sty` then `tlmgr info wibble.sty` would reveal what texlive package contains that latex package.

Comment: you don't need to add .tfm specifically, to see related entries including the target you could `tlmgr info ts1-qtmr` and also get the adjoining info for when you specify italics e.g. both texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/tex-gyre/ts1-qtmri.tfm and non italic forms are in tex-gyre **beware do not shorten to ts1** there are hundreds for example try `tlmgr info ts1-qtm`